# Appium setup on Mac machine

Tags: ios, macos, automation, appium

I am trying to use Appium on mac Machine.

I am getting the below error, I tried unistalling the appium and installiing it.

When I tried to run the command directly, I am able to launch the app. Please help.

Error is

> info: Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate /Users/vchaudha/Desktop/InternationalMountains.app -e UIASCRIPT /Volumes/Appium/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/uiauto/bootstrap.js -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
>
> info: And extra without-delay env: {"DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES":"/Volumes/Appium/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd4/InstrumentsShim.dylib","LIB_PATH":"/Volumes/Appium/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd4"}
>   info: And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
>
> info: [INST STDERR] Instruments Usage Error : (null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Got the resolution of this. So for others who gets stuck with this error.

*Do not try to run the Appium from image but copy it into applications directory and then run from there.*